# The same strings should be equal but they are not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've spent a couple of hours googling why two same strings according to python are not the same.

The purpose of the code is to find the longest sub-string where prefix and suffix are equal.

I was debugging it and stored values in memory. It looks the same.

Instead of `... == i` have tried `is` operator. Still the same problem.

```
s = 'aaaaaaa'
l = len(s)
i = 1
prefix = 0
suffix = 0
for v in s: 
    if (i < l):
        prefix = s[:i]
        suffix = s[l-i:] # idk maybe this cause some problem
        i += 1
    if (prefix.strip() == suffix.strip()):
        print(len(prefix ))
```

**EDIT:** I dont know why but code started working. Topic can be closed.

Comment: Which strings are supposed to be the same? And why are you inializing `prefix` and `suffix` to 0?

Comment: What is the purpose of the character `v`?

Comment: The code you post works as expected. (I get all numbers printed).

Comment: Which strings do you think are not equal?

Comment: Isn't the suffix actually `suffix = s[i+1:l]`?

Comment: if you check in debugger if statement after 1st loop is all the time false, but it should be always true. so length of prefix should be printed like 1,2,3,4,5, etc, but its printed only 1

Comment: Guys, you problably tell me that i am an idiot or whatever, but I restarted the computer and now its working fine.
Damn, I have spend 2h to figure out the problem which suddenly dissapear.... No idea how to explain it.

Comment: @Vincent Fourmond: Really all? I get two "6" in the end, because of the `i < l` error (should be `i <= l`).

Comment: You can delete bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please **RE-EDIT** your question, members of **StackOverflow** can't help you without an Understandable (to be expected; natural, reasonable) problem. This is a **awesome community** once you have a ***SPECIFIC*** (instance of an issue) problem they'll be able to help you including me.

What are you trying to compare? Using ***IF*** statement you're able to compare **2**  (or more) values

```
faulty_fuses_new_variable = 'heyman!' #Added a new variable
s = 'aaaaaaa' #String type variable ---> or you can refer to it as  -  list  of characters  -     -- index [0] is the first element 
print(s[0])
    #if that's easier for you

    l = len(s) # This is an integer value variable for example for your case l = 7

    if len(s)==len(faulty_fuses_new_variable): #Checks if the lenght of the variables are the SAME 7==7 in this case.
        print ('{0} variable is the same lenght as {1} variable'.format(faulty_fuses_new_variable,s))
    #Think of {0} and {1} as place in the string that we will input our values with example :  .format(someVar,SomeOtherVar)
```

***Summary***  : There's no syntax Error in your code (IT RUNS !YAY! ) but there's a logical error obviously since you're asking for a solution. Therefore there needs to be a logical context to the **Question**, There are many sections where you can Learn - HOW TO WRITE A QUESTION - (Sometimes it's hard, been there, done that. Don't look for an easy solution look for **KNOWLEDGE** -->**INFORMATION** ) You can even post your would-be question on there just to get an idea of what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your post. The bug just somehow disappeared. My code is working as it should.